# How to add items in a recycler view from a different class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Have implemented a recycler view found on my notification fragments on adding itesm on the same fragments no problem occurs but when i try to add items from another fragment it throws and eror JavaNullPointException.

**here is my fragment that has the recycler view**

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_notificationcict, container, false);






        notimodels = new ArrayList<> ();

        mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.notificationsRecycler);


        fillNotification (R.drawable.logo, "OCApp", "Welcome to Online Clearance Application,Get cleared now , avoid queing up in offices , save time and money.",+ minutes+"min");

        // get data from the notificiation
        return  v;
    }




    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart ();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        fillNotification (R.drawable.logo, "OCApp", "Welcome to Online Clearance Application,Get cleared now , avoid queing up in offices , save time and money.",+ minutes+"min");
    }



   public void fillNotification(int mImage, String mtext, String mtext2, String mDate)
    {
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (getContext ());
        mAdapter = new NotificationAdapter (notimodels);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        notimodels.add (0,new NotificationModel (mImage,mtext,mtext2,mDate));
    }
}
```

**When i try to call the function from other fragments like tis forexample""

```
NotificationFragmentCict notificationFragmentCict =new NotificationFragmentCict ();
        notificationFragmentCict.fillNotification (R.drawable.bursar, "Bursar", "your clreard","min");
```

**My App crushes and throws this error**

```
Process: com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp, PID: 3380
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

**The problem is this one This error is showing because your fragment's view is not created yet. That's why recyclerview is null and you're invoking setHasFixedSize(...) method on you null recyclerview. but icant solve it any help guys**

Comment: When you create a new fragment this way: "new NotificationFragmentCict ()", the onCreateView method is not called because the layout has not been inflated and so there is no recycler view. (Try to put a break point inside onCreateView and see if it is called after that initialization). You need to inflate the fragment somewhere using the frag manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the recycler view which you left out of the function `fillNotification`:

```
mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.notificationsRecycler);
```

you also need the ArrayList in the second fragment:

```
  notimodels = new ArrayList<> ();
```

Comment: thanks so much but the problem is how to initialise the recycler out of the v.findviewbyId cannot be used on my function that is outside on create

Comment: You can call findViewById from anywhere, if it is a different recyclerview than the other fragment, you can pass it as a parameter